# Simple Java IDE for Mac?

Tags: java, macos, ide

I am looking for a FREE app that's a bit smarter than a text editor. I want something that can compile Java programs, as a bonus it may have some kind of code-sense.

The programs I'll make are simple console apps that I have to do for school assignments.

I really don't think I'll need a full-blown IDE. After this class, I don't plan on using Java in the future.

I came across [this app](http://homepage.mac.com/jmacmullin/), but it seems it won't work on OS X 10.5+.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Eclipse? You can do C++ programming there too!

Comment: Have you tried TextMate with the Java Bundle? Its not free though. Otherwise I'd probably say NetBeans or Eclipse... Those are full out IDEs though.

Comment: Try emacs (e.g., Aquamacs) with JDE

Comment: I use Eclipse on the PC and I feel it's more than I need. Netbeans and Eclipse seem to be targeted at professional JAVA developers. I'm hoping to find something really simple.

Comment: Hopefully by the time you finish this course, you will be aware that it is spelled 'Java' not 'JAVA'.  Java is a proper name, not an acronym.

Comment: Yes, that's much more pleasing to the eyes.

Answer (score 11):

I'd cast my vote for [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), even if you only think you'll be using Java for a few months. Having a capable IDE to provide error-checking and auto-completion capabilities will save you a bundle of time over using any basic text editor. (And, as [The Elite Gentleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251173/the-elite-gentleman) has already pointed out, if you take to the environment, you can always continue to use it to develop in a variety of other languages after the course is over!)

Answer (score 7):

Here are common GUI based options that you can have a closer look at:

**Fullsize IDEs**

- http://eclipse.org/
- http://netbeans.org/
- http://jetbrains.com/idea/

**Smarter Text Editors**

- http://macromates.com/
- http://sublimetext.com/
- http://chocolatapp.com/

**Note:**
I chose the ones that make sense for me.
There are also tons of other choices like Smultron, BBEdit and others. You can start browsing for them here:

http://alternativeto.net/software/eclipse/?platform=mac

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a few years later...
"CodeRunner" has a simple code editor and a "Run" button - It won't be as good as a full featured editor, but it could be perfect for the type of class work assignments Louis originally asked about.

Comment: It doesn't have a trial version and every time getting a refund from iTunes Store is irritating.

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be [IntelliJ Idea Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html), but since it still lacks a bunch of features, I'd also cast my vote for Eclipse.

Comment: Even a stripped down IntelliJ is better than Eclipse.

Comment: What I don't like about Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA is that I have to create a project for each assignment. My professor just wants the .java file so it complicates things as far as preparing it for submission.

Comment: You could just submit the .java file created in an IDE as well. Any decent IDE will require you to create a project in order to handle classpath and build build settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need all futures of such IDE as Eclipse or NetBeans, you can use powered text editor, for example - TextMate (http://macromates.com/).

Comment: Even though its not free, TextMate looks great. I've got the trial, unfortunately the output window is read-only.

Comment: Coda is also a nice, non-free editor for the Mac, and although it does not seem to be built for Java Developers it might be worth checking out. http://panic.com/coda/

Answer (score 1):

Try one of following:

1. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx)
2. [EditRocket](http://www.editrocket.com/features/java_editor.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is the Java Wiki Integrated Development Environment or JavaWIDE for short.  It's easy to use, not too many complex features, and it's entirely browser based.  JavaWIDE will work on Mac just fine.  Check it out at http://www.javawide.org, or start coding immediately at http://sandbox.javawide.org (free & no account needed).

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned I should be able to work offline.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found MochaCode: http://syntori.com/mochacode/ - it is a native OS X IDE for Java, but doesn't appear to have been updated since 2008.  Interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a minimal version of NetBeans, although it is a "full-blown IDE" by your definition, it is very easy to use right away. I personally use NetBeans as a prototyping tool when I need to test something or write a small Java application.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard other people recommend BlueJ for simple Java work.  It might be just what you need:  http://www.bluej.org/download/download.html

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I've had trouble getting the hang of this though — compilation issues.